# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError on Android 4.2.2 Devices

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy, noclassdeffounderror, android-multidex

I have an Android application and need to implement bluetooth low energy functionality. The BLE features should run on devices with Android API Level > 26 (Android 8), but the app should also start on devices with Android > 17 (Android 4.2). I have tested this app on Android 8 and 4.4 and there are no problems. If i let the app run on devices with Android 4.2.2 it crashes just after the start. Logs look like that:

> AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/bluetooth/BluetoothGatt
>
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt" on path: /data/app/com.android.codeDevice-1.apk

Android project configuration:

```
compileSdkVersion = 26
buildToolsVersion = '27.0.3'
minSdkVersion = 17
targetSdkVersion = 26
```

Also MultiDex is enabled and my main application extends MultiDexApplication.

Is there a need to config the proguard rules? I don't know how to fix that, thank you for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As can be seen in the documentation, BluethoothGatt was added in API level 18: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGatt .

Your current minSDK is 17. You either have to update your minSDK or find another solution (e.g. 3rd party lib, etc.)

Comment: Is there any possibility to skip the classes for lower API Levels? They are not used on devices < 26.

Comment: You can surround the code that uses these classes with if statements like so: ``if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26)``